# How to get id of created category?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

how can I get a category id from a newly created category?

```
message.guild.channels.create(` | ${args[0]}`, { type: 'category' });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `.create()` method returns a **Promise**.
From that sense, we could either await the creation of it in an asynchronous function, or simply use the `.then()` function to take the newly created category as an object, and return it's id.

```
/**
* const category = await message.guild.channels.create(` | ${args[0]}`, { type: 'category' });
* console.log(category.id)
*/
message.guild.channels.create(` | ${args[0]}`, { type: 'category' })
.then(category => console.log(category.id));
```